# How to output contents of _aud table as JSON?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-envers

I would like to display the contents of my _aud table in a JSON array like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "rev":1,
    "revtype":0,
    "created_date":xxxx,
    "modified_date":yyyy
  }
]
```

How do I write my controller GET method?

I had written something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/audit/{id}")
public List<Revisions<Long, Person>> getRevisions(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
 return personRepository.findRevisions(id);
}
```

Unfortunately Spring Boot/Jackson cannot convert Revisions to JSON.

How do I view the records from the _aud table as a JSON array?

I am using Spring Data Envers and my repository class implements RevisionRepository<Person, Long, Long>.